# Direction of pressure in fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

ok so my friend told me that in a container, the pressure exerted by the walls on the liquid in the container act in the upward direction.Is he correct ? so what I am imagining is a cylindrical container kept on the ground. according to me the pressure by the wall of the container should act perpendicular to the surface of the wall.Am i going wrong somewhere ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressure at a point in a static fluid is independent of direction.

http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~jps7/Aircraft%20Design%20Resources/Sydney%20aerodynamics%20for%20students/fprops/statics/node4.html

The *force* exerted by the walls on the liquid will be pointing inwards. Imagine if there is a hole in the container and water is liquid out, it is easy to see that  you have to  apply a force inwards in order to prevent the liquid from leaking. Since the force is proportional to the area of the hole, you'd want a  dimensionally equivalent form of pressure in order to eliminate the dependence on area. And that is *stress*. (Note that stress is not a scalar nor a vector - it is a tensor)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(mechanics)

Comment: Ok so what happens if the container is not cylindrical ?
Suppose we take a container like a bucket ( frustum of a cone).will there be any upward force now?

Comment: Yes since the force will have a Z component in addition to X and Y component, since the surface's normal is no longer in the XY plane but slightly tilted.

Answer (score 5):

Pressure is a scalar and does not have a direction. This is discussed in some detail in the answers to [Define Pressure at A point. Why is it a Scalar?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18255/define-pressure-at-a-point-why-is-it-a-scalar), though this might be a bit technical.

When you measure a pressure you are actually measuring the force applied to a surface. For some small bit of surface $\delta {\bf A}$, the force produced on that surface due to a pressure $P$ is:

$$ \delta {\bf F} = P \delta {\bf A} $$

and the direction of the force is normal to the surface. So it's the orientation of the surface that determines the direction of the force.

We use small surface elements $\delta {\bf A}$ so that we can apply the formula to curved surfaces. Your particular case is a lot simpler, and you are basically correct. However note that when you say:

> the **pressure** by the wall of the container should act perpendicular to the surface of the wall

Note that this should be:

> the **force** by the wall of the container should act perpendicular to the surface of the wall

Comment: I'm likely to be incorrect, but as far as I know, pressure is defined as compressive isotropic normal stress. By this definition pressure has direction sign (positive for compressive?) and a magnitude? Also, by this definition, it seems that pressure is defined as a special case of stress (simple stress situation). Also, if this is true, can fluid pressure be called fluid stress? My source: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_%28mechanics%29#Simple_stresses

Comment: @jake Yes. My answer to a [spinoff of this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142660/mathematical-reasoning-for-fluid-pressure-as-a-scalar) touches on this a little.

Comment: @ChrisWhite which part(s) of my comment are you saying yes to?  Also, I will look at your spinoff question.  I had [posted a question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107824/what-is-the-difference-between-stress-and-pressure) that also touched on these matters as well.