# Pressure of water in all directions

Tags: forces, pressure, definition, fluid-statics

As far as I understand, pressure acts downwards on a surface of a body in water because pressure $P$ is given by

$$
P = \frac{F}{A} = \frac{m \, g}{A}
$$
where $F$ is the gravitational force on the body of mass $m$ with surface area $A$, and $g$ is the gravitational acceleration.

[image: Pressure on a body immersed in water]

But I cannot see how pressure acts in *all* directions; namely, at the sides where apparently $F \neq mg$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mathematical Reasoning for Fluid Pressure as a Scalar](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142660/)

Comment: [Also search for *pressure scalar* for lots more related questions.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=pressure+scalar)

Comment: There are some advanced stuff. But, can anyone give a brief explanation about it?